# Ajax to stay in same Jsp page

Tags: ajax, jsp

I need a simple AJAX code to stay in same jsp page after i click submit button.It should not refresh the page. I have researched a lot. But didnt get a simple one.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find a simple form submit example in this [link](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/)

you can add a button `<button id='submit-btn'>Submit</button>` and make ajax call on click of that as in below code.

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function (e) {
            var postData = $('#ajaxform').serializeArray();
    var formURL = $('#ajaxform').attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //data: return data from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
        });
```